# is it possible to list a range of numbers in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

here's what i have:

```
keys = {
# first row
(range(0, 99), range(550, 700)): "q",
(range(100, 199), range(550, 700)): "w",
(range(200, 299), range(550, 700)): "e",
(range(300, 399), range(550, 700)): "r",
(range(400, 499), range(550, 700)): "t",
(range(500, 599), range(550, 700)): "y",
(range(600, 699), range(550, 700)): "u",
(range(700, 799), range(550, 700)): "i",
(range(800, 899), range(550, 700)): "o",
(range(900, 999), range(550, 700)): "p",
# space
(range(0, 47), range(701, 999)): " ",
(range(48, 147), range(850, 999)): " ",
# second row
(range(48, 147), range(701, 849)): "a",
(range(148, 247), range(701, 849)): "s",
(range(248, 347), range(701, 849)): "d",
(range(348, 447), range(701, 849)): "f",
(range(448, 547), range(701, 849)): "g",
(range(548, 647), range(701, 849)): "h",
(range(648, 747), range(701, 849)): "j",
(range(748, 847), range(701, 849)): "k",
(range(848, 947), range(701, 849)): "l",
# back
(range(948, 999), range(701, 999)): "asad",
(range(848, 999), range(850, 999)): "aasd",
# third row
(range(148, 247), range(850, 849)): "z",
(range(248, 347), range(850, 849)): "x",
(range(348, 447), range(850, 849)): "c",
(range(448, 547), range(850, 849)): "v",
(range(548, 647), range(850, 849)): "b",
(range(648, 747), range(850, 849)): "n",
(range(748, 847), range(850, 849)): "m"}
```

i did not get an output when i ran a for loop checking if (778, 300) was in the list. is it possible to use ranges in a list? and if it is, how would i do that because i'm clearly doing it wrong lol.

Comment: The first key (for example) in your dictionary is the tuple `(range(0, 99), range(550, 700))`.  To retrieve the value associated with that key, you'd have to provide a key that has the same hash value, and compares as equal to the original key: in other words, another instance of the tuple `(range(0, 99), range(550, 700))`.  Trying to use `(778, 300)` as a key will never even get to the point of comparing equality, since its hash value will almost certainly not match any of your keys.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and what did you expect the output to be when you passed (778, 300)?

Comment: you can use ranges in lists, For your purpose something like `778 in range(748, 847)` would return `True`, what you need to do is loop over your dict keys and check if the first element of your tuple 778 in your case is in the first element of dict keys, if so check for the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough this is possible. Not via a direct dictionary lookup (though @DeepSpace may be right about a `UserDict` wrapper in this regard), but via a function that *walks* the dictionary.  
Don't expand the ranges into tuples, leave them as-is as they are perfectly hashable.  
But to make it work easier, we can rearrange the data structure. 
I'm only using a subset of the data for my example solution:

```
dictionary = {
    range(550, 700): {
        range(100, 199): "w",
        range(200, 299): "e",
        range(300, 399): "r",
        range(400, 499): "t",
        range(500, 599): "y",
        range(600, 699): "u",
        range(700, 799): "i",
        range(800, 899): "o",
        range(900, 999): "p",
        },

    range(701, 849): {
        range(48, 147): "a",
        range(148, 247): "s",
        range(248, 347): "d",
        range(348, 447): "f",
        range(448, 547): "g",
        range(548, 647): "h",
        range(648, 747): "j",
        range(748, 847): "k",
        range(848, 947): "l",
        },
}

def in_dictionary(key):
    for number_range in dictionary:
        if key[0] in number_range:
            sub_dictionary = dictionary[number_range]

            for number_range in sub_dictionary:
                if key[1] in number_range:
                    return sub_dictionary[number_range]

    return None

key = (778, 300)

print(in_dictionary(key))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
d
>
```

Which if you work through the ranges, is the correct answer! 
Yes, I'm reversing the search order of the OP's example key, but that's the only order that makes sense given the data, otherwise it wouldn't be found.